# Which exchanges are good for altcoins?

Tags: exchanges, altcoin

To trade Altcoins nowadays, which exchanges are good to use?

Bittrex and Bitfinex are both out of option due to their temporary block on new accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bittrex ... out of option" ok, i noticed, but if you ask "Which exchanges are good for altcoins?" the answer i think is mainly:
[binance](https://www.binance.com/), [poloniex](https://poloniex.com/), [bittrex](https://bittrex.com/), [cryptopia](https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/), [yobit](https://yobit.net/)

Comment: Just used binance, sent money from GDAX, and the fund (BTC) never arrived!!

Comment: it arrived. Just takes time!